# iPhone:Compile C++ files in Xcode without modifying the file extension

Tags: iphone, c++, xcode

How can i compile C++ files without modifying the extension in my Xcode 4.0 based project? Setting "LLVM GCC 4.2" in C/C++ compiler version setting is only fine? 
Please suggest me to solve this.

Thank you!

Comment: its unclear what you mean by extentions.

Comment: I meant extension of file. somewhere i read, we have to make the file as .mm (or) .cpp.cpp to compile the c++ files using Xcode. Can we compile C++ files directly and without modifying extension?

Answer (score 2):

In the utilities side panel, click the File Inspector button.
There is a drop down box that allows you to select the file type. You can select 'C++ Source' from in there, which sounds like it will compile the file as C++.